# Serial brick camera

Tags: serial, camera, ftdi

I bought [this serial electronic brick camera](http://www.robotshop.com/seeedstudio-electronic-brick-serial-cmos-camera-2.html) from Robot shop recently. I connected it to a [Spark Fun FT232R](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/718) shield. I am able to open my virtual COM port but I am not able to capture any images.

This is what I did on the spark fun shield's end:

1. I removed the solder jumper and connected 5V to VccIO, and GND to GND.
2. I connected the Rx to Tx and vice versa.
3. When I click on capture, the serial camera client just freezes.

Can anyone throw some light where am I going wrong?

Comment: What camera did you buy?

Comment: Have you tested your Spark Fun shield?

Comment: @Daniel: I bought this camera in the link below:http://www.robotshop.com/seeedstudio-electronic-brick-serial-cmos-camera-2.html. Yes I did test my Spark fun shield. It is getting enumerated as a Virtual Com Port

Comment: @Sai Ok. Now you can do another test. Make a short with TX and RX pins of your Spark Fun Shield. Send any data using a software like Hyperterminal. Everything you send, you have to receive. If you remove the short and try send a character again, and you won't receive nothing.

Comment: Are you level shifting to rs232 levels?

Comment: Good Question :)

Comment: Is the BTRate set Correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the device the manufacture will sometimes label RX and TX from either the DCE or DTE perspective. You need to make sure the transmit line of your one device is tied to the receive line of your second device and vice versa. Try crossing over your RX and TX with a null modem adapter and see if that helps. If you tied the transmit line of one device to the transmit line of the second the communication will not work.